# Read SQLite blob in php, written in c#

Tags: c#, php, sqlite

I write an image blob in SQlite db with c# and I try to read with PHP, but I have some problems.

PHP doesn't show the image.

If I write the file on the disk, the image is corrupted.. ....

```
string queryInsertAnagraficaSqlLite = @"INSERT INTO utentiLite (user_name,first_name,last_name,SQL_iscrizione_num,SQL_iscrizione_prov,SQL_bcode,SQL_codice_fiscale,image,conferma) VALUES
(@username,@nome,@cognome,@numIscrizione,@provIscrizione,@barCode,@codiceFiscale,@Foto,@conferma)";

SQLiteCommand cmdInsertAnagrafica = new SQLiteCommand(queryInsertAnagraficaSqlLite, conn);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cognome", cognome);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numIscrizione", Iscrizione);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@provIscrizione", provIscrizione);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barCode", barCode);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codiceFiscale", codiceFiscale);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conferma", conferma);
cmdInsertAnagrafica.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foto", image);
```

The image is an byte array.

This is the PHP code that reads the image.

```
<?php 
//header('Content-Type:image/jpeg;base64');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$dbFile = realpath('./').'/includi.db' ;
ob_end_flush();
$dbLink=sqlite3_open($dbFile) or   die("Could not open database");
$query = "SELECT image FROM utentiLite WHERE user_name='$id'";
$result = sqlite3_query($dbLink, $query);
while($row = sqlite3_fetch_array($result)) { 
    file_put_contents($id.".jpg",$row['image']);
    echo "<img src='".$id.".jpg'> <br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Has the array the correct size or the size is corrupted too?

Comment: What type does `image` have in C#?

Comment: Have a look at the file with a sqlite viewer and see what kind of information is actually stored there - it'll allow you to find out if it's stored wrong or if it's the retrieval that fails.